# Conditional FrameworkElements depending on DataContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatrigger, frameworkelement

In my M-V-VM application I have to show the user's avatar. The image is provided in a property of type ImageSource the ViewModel object. So that's what I have currently:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=UserAvatar}"/>
```

However, some users may not have an avatar configured, so UserAvatar is `null`. In that case I want to show a default avatar. Noone but the view must know about the default image, because it's just a concern of presentation.

So how can I either show the image with the given ImageSource, or a specific resource if ImageSource is `null`. Do I have to use some kind of DataTemplate with DataTriggers? Since now I only used them for ItemsControls, so I don't know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you guessed correctly, templates and triggers are indeed your friend here.

Here is an implementation using the `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=UserAvatar}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding}"/>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source" Value="--your awesome default image here--" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

And in the situation when your default thingy is no `ImageSource`, and you wish to play around a bit with other controls, you can always resort to the `Visibilty` property:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=UserAvatar}">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding}" />
                <Canvas x:Name="defaultImage" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter TargetName="defaultImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: But how about the default image if there's no UserAvatar? Another ContentControl?
Seems that I need a not-null DataTrigger. I just discovered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356194/wpf-datatrigger-where-value-is-not-null, which proposes a custom ValueConverter.

Comment: D'uh. Should learn to read. You're solution is exactly what I was looking for, Arcturus. There's only one point left before I accept your answer: the default avatar isn't an ImageSource but a canvas, so the Image element must be replaced somehow (or hidden)

Comment: It works, except that a DataTemplate can only have one child. Wrapping the Image and the Canvas in a Grid helps :)

Comment: Ah my bad.. didnt compile it.. ;) Glad I could help!