# Silverlight: Default value in Combobox

Tags: silverlight

I would like to display a default text in the combobox. For example, "Choose a person" message. could you please help me out.

Please note that I am using databinding from domaincontext

Thank you !!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To achieve this, I used a derived `ExtendedComboBox` class which extends the built-in `ComboBox` class. You can find the source code of this class in [my blog post](http://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/silverlight-combobox-prompt-text-if-an-item-isnt-selected/) or below.

After you add this class to your project, you can use this XAML code to display a default value:

```
<local:ExtendedComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ...Whatever...}" NotSelectedText="Select item..." />
```

Also, here is the [test page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8047386/WordPress/SilverlightComboBox/ComboBoxWithPromptValue/ComboBoxWithPromptValueTestPage.html) with this control. I think that the second combobox is that what you need.
[image: example of the extended ComboBox]

Full code of this class:

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = ExtendedComboBox.StateNormal, GroupName = ExtendedComboBox.GroupItemsSource)]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = ExtendedComboBox.StateNotSelected, GroupName = ExtendedComboBox.GroupItemsSource)]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = ExtendedComboBox.StateEmpty, GroupName = ExtendedComboBox.GroupItemsSource)]
public class ExtendedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public const string GroupItemsSource = "ItemsSourceStates";
    public const string StateNormal = "Normal";
    public const string StateNotSelected = "NotSelected";
    public const string StateEmpty = "Empty";

    private ContentPresenter selectedContent;

    public ExtendedComboBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ComboBox);
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.selectedContent = this.GetTemplateChild("ContentPresenter") as ContentPresenter;

        // This event can change the NotSelected state
        this.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => this.SetTextIfEmpty();

        // Set a state at start
        this.SetTextIfEmpty();
    }

    // This method can change the Empty state
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        this.SetTextIfEmpty();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text if the SelectedItem property is null.
    /// </summary>
    public string NotSelectedText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NotSelectedTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NotSelectedTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NotSelectedTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NotSelectedText", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(" "));

    /// <summary>
    /// Text if there are no items in the ComboBox at all.
    /// </summary>
    public string EmptyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(EmptyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EmptyTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EmptyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EmptyText", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes the state of this control and updates the displayed text.
    /// </summary>
    protected void SetTextIfEmpty()
    {
        if (this.selectedContent == null || !(this.selectedContent.Content is TextBlock))
            return;
        var text = this.selectedContent.Content as TextBlock;

        if (this.SelectedItem == null && this.Items != null && this.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            text.Text = this.NotSelectedText;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, ExtendedComboBox.StateNotSelected, true);
        }
        else if (this.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            text.Text = this.EmptyText ?? this.NotSelectedText;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, ExtendedComboBox.StateEmpty, true);
        }
        else VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, ExtendedComboBox.StateNormal, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to allow the user to select the "Not Selected" state after a selection has already been made?

Comment: @Jordan Just set `.SelectedItem = null;`

Comment: In code, I know. I'm talking about the user being able to set it back to "Not Selected".

Comment: @Jordan Then you can use the built-in combobox control and add 1 item to the beginning of the items collection.

Comment: That was what I was trying to avoid. You think this would be a common use case, but I guess its not. I am binding the combo box to objects not strings, so it makes things kind of messy. *sigh* Thanks, i really like your `ExtendedComboBox`, and I will definitely use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
theComboBox.SelectedItem  = yourDataItem;
```

alternatively, set the selected index:

```
theComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

---

Edit

If ItemSource is bound, you want to override the combo's `DataContextChanged` and then use one of the above lines to set the index/selected item.

---

However, if you don't want the default text to be selectable, you will have to do something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf).

Comment: I am binding the dropdown menu to a data context :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use set value method to insert a value at a particular position.
It may be not best option but it works for me.

```
var array= APPTasks.ListPhysician.OrderBy(e => e.phyFName).ThenBy(e => e.phyLName).ToArray();

array.SetValue((new Physician { phyFName = "Select Attening Md", phyLName = "" }), 0);
```

just bring your data in a variable and use SetValue method.