# How to validate a combobox in silverlight 5 MVVM pattern

Tags: silverlight, validation, mvvm, combobox, design-patterns

How to validate a combobox in silverlight 5 (I am preparing a report in silverlight5 with MVVM pattern and on search button, if the checkbox is checked, the user has to select an item from the combobox..)
Also, i am using the below to set the default content text as "Select One"...is there any other better way to do it. The problem using below link is ..if i select an item from the combobox and then later i decide to keep it blank..i have no way of doing it but reload the webpage..

[Silverlight: Default value in Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149671/silverlight-default-value-in-combobox)

Any help would be much appreciated..please I need it urgently

Thanks in advance!!