# Adding default Item in ComboBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox

I want to add a default Item in `Combobox` at `0th Index` after I bind it. I tried to do it like this:

```
cboProductType.ItemsSource = e.Result;
cboProductType.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Products--");  //error on this line
```

but got error:

> Operation Not Supported on Read-only collection

What's the way of adding default items in `Silverlight` ComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BUT**

I assume You are using WPF and XAML try this:

[WPF Combobox DefaultValue (Please Select)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130763/wpf-combobox-defaultvalue-please-select)

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ListBoxItem>Please Select</ListBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource YOURDATASOURCE}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

**BUT**

If You are using Silverlight like You said:

Use: `NotSelectedText="--Select Products--"`

```
<local:ExtendedComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ...Whatever...}" NotSelectedText="--Select Products--" />
```

Source code of: `local:ExtendedComboBox` is on:

https://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/silverlight-combobox-prompt-text-if-an-item-isnt-selected/

[Silverlight: Default value in Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149671/silverlight-default-value-in-combobox)

**Alterntive**

Is create the default `ProductType` with text `"--Select Products--"` and then add to colection oj position 0;

```
e.Result.Add(new ProductType { Text =" --Select Products-- " });

cboProductType.ItemsSource = e.Result;
```

Something like that.

Comment: `Result.Add` doesn't take two arguments

Comment: OK, what is the type of e.Result?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<ProductType>`. `ProductType` is my class

Comment: Combobox does not contain a definition for `Text`. And no, I'm using `Silverlight`

Comment: Before i assume You are using WinForms, sorry. I Update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101675/discussion-between-goodeinstein-and-huma-ali).

Comment: I can't find `ExtendedComboBox` in my `ToolBox`

Comment: Source code of `ExtendedComboBox` is here 
 https://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/silverlight-combobox-prompt-text-if-an-item-isnt-selected/