# Set a default name to a combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a combobox filled with int's representing years. The years I have add them to an ObservableCollection, but my problem is when I load the project the combobox its blank by default. I want to set a default name to it, like "Years", but I don't want solution like set the isEditable to true, or inserting a string at the beginning. I want a pure xaml solution if it is posible.

This is my current xaml file:

```
<RSControls:SmoothScrollComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="compilationYearCombo" Margin="7,2.04,0,2.04"                                                                                     
                            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedYear}"
                            SelectedValuePath=""
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Years}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="" SelectionChanged="compilationYearCombo_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsEditable="False" SelectedIndex="0" IsReadOnly="False" Text="Years">

                        </RSControls:SmoothScrollComboBox>
```

I tried adding a `<TextBlock Text="Years" />` , but that only changed all the elements in the combo to "Years".

I apreciatte a detail explenation how to this, I am just a beginner with WPF.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf) help?

Comment: I tried that solution but I dont know what that CultureInfo parameter is...

Comment: check `System.Globalization` you would find it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a visibility  converter to your TextBlock

```
   <TextBlock
           Visibility="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=compilationYearCombo, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}"
           IsHitTestVisible="False"
           Text="Years" />
```

with this converter:

```
    public class NullToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I always get that it doesnt know about NullToVisibilityConverter

Comment: You'd need to add the NullToVisibilityConverter to your resources first of course

Answer (score 0):

To show the default text ' -- Select Value --' in Combo Box

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,18,0,0" Name="cmbExportData" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Text="-- Select Value --" AllowDrop="False" IsEditable="True" IsManipulationEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" />
```