# Default text of combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

i want a default text  on my combobox  as i have binded my combo box to certain list of items...here is my code of xaml file.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" 
          Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding projectList, ElementName=MainWin}"
          SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  
          SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
          Width="130" Background="White" BorderThickness="1"  
          FontFamily="/TimeSheet;component/Resources/#Open Sans" FontSize="12" 
          Canvas.Right="159" Canvas.Top="8" Height="47">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding _name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: it helps, if you ask a concrete question on the end of the text. it also if you describe what you already tried to achieve that - so you show own efforts instead of blindly letting others work for you. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it atlast by taking a new textblock and applying a trigger on it,and using the IsNullConverter class it helped

```
<TextBlock Text="Select Project" IsHitTestVisible="False" FontFamily="/TimeSheet;component/Resources/#Open Sans" FontSize="14" Canvas.Right="191" Canvas.Top="22">
                        <TextBlock.Resources>
                            <Converters:IsNullConverter x:Key="isNullConverter"/>
                        </TextBlock.Resources>
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ProjectComboBox,Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Text Property

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox"
  IsEditable=True
  Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" ....../>
```

or

You can use SelectedIndex Property and set it to 0(SelectedIndex=0) which displays first item in Source given.

or

you can do like this as in the link [How to display default text "--Select Team --" in combo box on pageload in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf)

Comment: xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Resources.Converters" , this   line in xaml gives an error,what to write exactly and is there anything to import,i am missing it???????

Comment: i was not embedding the converter properly in my project folder

Comment: you also suggested a very nice way but actually i didnt wanted that way...i have posted my code down check it out

Comment: can you help me out on a question i have posted,i am not able to get alpha icon transparency,check out my question if you have any solution

Comment: Yeah i saw.Check the Converters class namespace.Is it MyProject.Resources.Converters..?

Comment: help me out on the question of alpha icon transparency i have posted please if you can

Comment: Ok i will check the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DefaultText="Not Specified"
```

- edit ah sorry I was thinking of my control 
  have a read of this [How to show text in combobox when no item selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064133/how-to-show-text-in-combobox-when-no-item-selected)

Comment: I think there is no property like "DefaultText" in combobox and also in text block

Comment: I cannot change the C# code as i have my xml file binded to it i.e to the list of combobox  ,can we have any solution using XAML code only

Answer (score 0):

> Try this in page load or form load

```
 comboBox.SelectedItem = null;
 comboBox.Text = "---select an item---";
```