# Toggle between combo-boxes and persist label in combo-box in WPF(XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, wpf-controls, dropdown

I am new to WPF and unable to implement the below scenario :
Three drop down boxes side by side. I have tried using Combo Box. I have tried to explain the problems with the help of an image
Example : (refer image)

- I want to select any one - name/school/email. Say I select **Name1** , then I should not be able to choose any of the other two dropdowns - School/Email.However, in my implementation I am still able to select values from the other dropdowns as well.
- If I change my mind and move to the **School** dropdown and leave the **Name** dropdown, the **Name** dropdown should change the value from **Name1**(which was selected in Step 1) to **Name**(which is the title of that button), However, in my implementation both the selections - **Name1** and **School1** are persisting.

I tried implementing this with the help of these two posts and the nearest I could get was as I mentioned in the example above : [How to display default text "--Select Team --" in combo box on pageload in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf) and [Name on combobox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898222/name-on-combobox-in-wpf)[image]

PS : Name/School/ Email are NOT watermarks. They are the title of the button which is there by default as you land on that page/window.
Any help/resources is appreciated.

Comment: "_I should not be able to choose any of the other two dropdowns_" "_If I change my mind and move to the School dropdown_" So do you able or not to access another comboboxes??

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question completely. I meant to say that if I change my mind and select an option  from any of the other two(School/Email). then my Name1 selection should change back to Name(the name on the dropdown button) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selection changed event of the comboboxes to set the text of each if you are going to code in code-behind:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbName" ItemsSource="{Binding NameList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Text="Name"
                  SelectionChanged="cmbName_SelectionChanged" MinWidth="80" Margin="10" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSchool" ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Text="School"
                  SelectionChanged="cmbSchool_SelectionChanged" MinWidth="80" Margin="10" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbEmail" ItemsSource="{Binding EmailList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Text="Email"
                  SelectionChanged="cmbEmail_SelectionChanged" MinWidth="80" Margin="10" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

In the selection changed of the Name combobox do the following:

```
private void cmbName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{      
        if(cmbName.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            cmbSchool.SelectedItem = null;
            cmbSchool.Text = "School";
            cmbEmail.SelectedItem = null;
            cmbEmail.Text = "Email";
        }
}
```

Do the same for each of the other comboboxes; just change the combobox names respectively.

If you are using MVVM, then bind the SelectedItem and the Text property of each of the combobox and write a common method which sets the selected items to null and also the text property inside the setter of each of the bound SelectedItems respectively.