# Display default text in combobox not working

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am using WPF. I have been battling to solve this problem. I tried to follow several advices from google but it didnt work for me. I cannot manage to default "--Select Car--" in the combobox. I have tried to put Text="--Select Cars--" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" which is not working. It still displays "Toyota" as default. Look below here:

```
<DockPanel xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="cmbCarListItems">
            <sys:String>Toyota</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Kia</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Audi</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <ComboBox Name="cmbCarList" 
              Text="--Select Cars--" 
              IsEditable="True"
              Cursor="Hand" 
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource cmbCarListItems}" 
              SelectionChanged="cmbCarList_SelectionChanged">
    </ComboBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Your code help much appreciated!!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf.

Comment: yes i have read this link and tried their advices. not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was working for me:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="cmbCarListItems">
            <sys:String>Toyota</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Kia</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Audi</sys:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <!-- Not using IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" -->
    <ComboBox Name="cmbCarList" 
              Text="--Select Cars--" 
              IsEditable="True"
              Cursor="Hand"
              ItemsSource="{StaticResource cmbCarListItems}"  
              SelectionChanged="cmbCarList_SelectionChanged">
    </ComboBox>

</Grid>
```

Comment: yes i have done this the same. it is still not working. i think maybe css may affect it. dont you think so?

Comment: What do you mean by CSS? XAML resources and styles?

Comment: The `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property broke it for me! Do you really need it?

Comment: i just removed css. the result still the same. i dont understand why default text cannot display.

Comment: yay you are right about IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem. once i removed it, it is working. Phew!!! i cannot remember why i added it lol. thanks very much