# How to make all controls resize accordingly proportionally when window is maximized?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

When I clicked on the maximize button the window is maximized but the controls are not resized proportionally. What is the best way to make the controls resize accordingly? I am using MVVM.

Here is my code.

```
<Window x:Class="DataTransfer.View.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Icon="/DataTransfer;component/View/Images/ms_msnexplore.gif"

        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="600">
    <!--Style="{DynamicResource OfficeStyle}"-->
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="/DataTransfer;component/View/WindowBase.xaml" />-->
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="/DataTransfer;component/Themes/WPFThemes/CalendarResource.xaml" />-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="22" />
        <DatePicker Name="dp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Text="aaa" GotFocus="DateGotFocused" LostFocus="OnLeaveArchiveDate"/>
        <Calendar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="t1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="337,23,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" LostFocus="LeaveField" />
        <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="88,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ComboBox Name="combo" IsEditable="False" Text="aaa" IsReadOnly="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
                  Focusable="True" GotFocus="ComboBoxGotFocused" >
            <ComboBoxItem>January</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>February</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="260,184,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text_Block" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: wrap you main `Grid` in a `ViewBox` or set the correct Margins/Alignments

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In WPF there are certain 'container' controls that automatically resize their contents and there are some that don't.

Here are some that do *not* resize their contents (I'm guessing that you are using one or more of these):

```
StackPanel
WrapPanel
Canvas
TabControl
```

Here are some that *do* resize their contents:

```
Grid
UniformGrid
DockPanel
```

Therefore, it is almost always preferable to use a `Grid` instead of a `StackPanel` unless you do *not* want automatic resizing to occur.  Please note that it is still possible for a `Grid` to *not* size its inner controls... it all depends on your `Grid.RowDefinition` and `Grid.ColumnDefinition` settings:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" /> <!--<<< Exact Height... won't resize -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!--<<< Will resize to the size of contents -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <!--<<< Will resize taking all remaining space -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

You can find out more about the `Grid` control from the [`Grid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) page on MSDN. You can also find out more about these container controls from the [WPF Container Controls Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Further resizing can be achieved using the [`FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) and [`FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx) properties. The default value of these properties is `Stretch` which will stretch elements to fit the size of their containing controls. However, when they are set to any other value, the elements will *not* stretch.

UPDATE >>>

In response to the questions in your comment:

Use the `Grid.RowDefinition` and `Grid.ColumnDefinition` settings to organise a basic structure first... it is common to add `Grid` controls into the cells of outer `Grid` controls if need be. You can also use the `Grid.ColumnSpan` and `Grid.RowSpan` properties to enable controls to span multiple columns and/or rows of a `Grid`.

It is most common to have at least one row/column with a `Height`/`Width` of `"*"` which will fill all remaining space, but you can have two or more with this setting, in which case the remaining space will be split between the two (or more) rows/columns. 'Auto' is a good setting to use for the rows/columns that are not set to '"*"', but it really depends on how you want the layout to be.

There is no `Auto` setting that you can use on the controls in the cells, but this is just as well, because we want the `Grid` to size the controls for us... therefore, we don't want to set the `Height` or `Width` of these controls at all.

The point that I made about the `FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment` and `FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment` properties was just to let you know of their existence... as their default value is already `Stretch`, you don't generally need to set them explicitly.

The `Margin` property is generally just used to space your controls out evenly... if you drag and drop controls from the Visual Studio Toolbox, VS will set the `Margin` property to place your control exactly where you dropped it but generally, this is *not* what we want as it will mess with the auto sizing of controls. If you do this, then just delete or edit the `Margin` property to suit your needs.

Comment: Sheridan, if I understand it correctly I need to divide the grid into many cells and put each control into the cells. the grid cell height and width should be set to auto. each individual control inside the grid cell should be set height and width to "AUTO" as well. And then use the MARGIN to set the size and  HORIZONTALALIGNMENT and VERTICALALIGNMENT to STRETCH. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your patience and clear explanation. Appreciate it.

Comment: One of the better answers for this type of question.

Comment: @Sheridan I am having to use a `MediaElement` to display a video. At times I want to highlight parts of the video with a rectangle. To do this is overlay a Canvas and draw on that (all using MVVM). The issue is when the window is re-sized the `MediaElement` scales differently to the `Canvas` and the rectangles get moved to an incorrect position - is there a way that you know to "bind" these two elements together so that they scale identically?

Comment: @MoonKnight, you really need to ask a new question, but in short, you can use a [`ViewBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) to scale the items in your `Canvas` panel in a similar way to the `MediaElement`.

Comment: Yeah, got there in the end. Thanks for your reply, most appreciated. Hope all is good...

Comment: @Sheridan, I have a grid with 2 rows and columns, and column height is Auto. In row 2 I have controls. In system scale 100%, the controls size is fine, but with system scale 125% the getting out of the row to the upper row. How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: @Alaa', I'd really need to see an example to help. I'd advise you to ask a new question here and I'm sure that you'll get an answer quickly.

Comment: A grid will size its contents, but it won't scale fixed-dimension elements. How do I get fixed-dimension elements to scale to match the size of my window?

Comment: Don't make them fixed size, or use a `Viewbox`.

Answer (score 4):

`myCanvas` is a Canvas control and Parent to all other controllers. This code works to  neatly resize to any resolution from 1366 x 768 upward. Tested up to 4k resolution 4096 x 2160

Take note of all the `MainWindow` property settings (`WindowStartupLocation`, `SizeToContent` and `WindowState`) - important for this to work correctly - `WindowState` for my user case requirement was `Maximized`:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="mainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" 
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow" 
     Title="MainWindow"  SizeChanged="MainWindow_SizeChanged"
    Width="1366" Height="768" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  
    <Canvas x:Name="myCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1356">
        <Image x:Name="maxresdefault_1_1__jpg" Source="maxresdefault-1[1].jpg" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.6" Height="767" Canvas.Left="-6" Width="1366"/>

        <Separator Margin="0" Background="#FF302D2D" Foreground="#FF111010" Height="0" Canvas.Left="-811" Canvas.Top="148" Width="766"/>
        <Separator Margin="0" Background="#FF302D2D" Foreground="#FF111010" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="210" Height="0" Canvas.Left="1653" Canvas.Top="102"/>
        <Image x:Name="imgscroll" Source="BcaKKb47i[1].png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="523" Canvas.Left="-3" Canvas.Top="122" Width="580">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="89.093"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

`.cs`:

```
 private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myCanvas.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
        myCanvas.Height = e.NewSize.Height;

        double xChange = 1, yChange = 1;

        if (e.PreviousSize.Width != 0)
            xChange = (e.NewSize.Width / e.PreviousSize.Width);

        if (e.PreviousSize.Height != 0)
            yChange = (e.NewSize.Height / e.PreviousSize.Height);

        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(myCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M11 * xChange, myCanvas.LayoutTransform.Value.M22 * yChange);
        myCanvas.LayoutTransform = scale;
        myCanvas.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Comment: This should be in a white paper.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's fairly simple to do.

On the window resize event handler, calculate how much the window has grown/shrunk, and use that fraction to adjust 1) Height, 2) Width, 3) Canvas.Top, 4) Canvas.Left properties of all the child controls inside the canvas.

Here's the code:

```
private void window1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            myCanvas.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
            myCanvas.Height = e.NewSize.Height;

            double xChange = 1, yChange = 1;

            if (e.PreviousSize.Width != 0)
            xChange = (e.NewSize.Width/e.PreviousSize.Width);

            if (e.PreviousSize.Height != 0)
            yChange = (e.NewSize.Height / e.PreviousSize.Height);

            foreach (FrameworkElement fe in myCanvas.Children )
            {   
                /*because I didn't want to resize the grid I'm having inside the canvas in this particular instance. (doing that from xaml) */            
                if (fe is Grid == false)
                {
                    fe.Height = fe.ActualHeight * yChange;
                    fe.Width = fe.ActualWidth * xChange;

                    Canvas.SetTop(fe, Canvas.GetTop(fe) * yChange);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(fe, Canvas.GetLeft(fe) * xChange);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what does myCanvas represent here?