# MVVM populating a combobox

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I am still new to `MVVM` (and C#) so please let me know if my question is unclear and I will update/clarify.

I have a `ListView` in my `xaml` with the following code:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <local:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OrdinalColumnDataTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem},
        Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=IndexConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>

<ListView.View>
    <GridView x:Name="gridView3">
        <GridViewColumn Header="#" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=OrdinalColumnDataTemplate}" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Name" />
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding License, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="License" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

It works as expected, It is populated with `Name` and `License` attributes of each element.
Now I would like to add a `ComboBox` and populate it with the unique `Names` of the same element which are shown in the `ListView`.

***QUESTION 1**: I have tested the below code but it does not work, how should the xml look like?*

```
<ComboBox Name="filterUserComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=licenseListView, ElementName=Name}"></ComboBox>
```

***QUESTION 2**: When the above works properly, how do I add an 'all' (or a single empty element) element to the ComboBox?*

Comment: Why dont you just insert a new entry at index 0 in your ResourceList to represent the "all" option?

Comment: maybe this question is what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf

Comment: @roqz, no, that is entirely another question.

Comment: to be sure, do you want an empty element in the comboBox like a null value?

Comment: @dennisschütz, yes. an empty element would suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve both questions myself. Hope it might help people in the future.

**ANSWER 1:** Turned out the xml was just a litte bit off.

```
<ComboBox Name="filterUserComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResourceList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"></ComboBox>
```

**ANSWER 2:** I researched this a long while and the solution is to actually change the MVVM which is populated in the ComboBox, so the source should actually include an empty/all option to be shown in the ComboBox.