# adding wpf combobox watermark

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

How to add watermark to WPF combo-box in an user control  ? I have seen many examples related to textbox but not a simplest solution using simple XAML or simple c# code related to combobox in wpf usercontrol . Give me some code or something but not links . I am totally a new fresher to WPF

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) On this website, it is customary for question authors to at least show their attempts at trying to fulfil their requirements, so that other users don't think that they want to have all of their work done for them. Are you stuck on a particular part of your implementation?

Comment: I wont bother explaining how i would go about it , so here's something you can download and use 
http://pwlodek.blogspot.co.il/2009/11/watermark-effect-for-wpfs-textbox.html

Comment: Look into the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf

Comment: @user3172564, I'm really not sure what you mean by *How can you expect me to ask a geek question*. I don't expect you to do that, but I (along with the rest of the community here) *do* expect you to follow the guidelines for using this website... yes, there *are* guidelines - please see the [Help Centre pages for asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). This website is *not* here to teach absolute beginners... that's what books, courses and tutorials are for. This website is for users that are really stuck on a particular part of their application and just need a little help.

Comment: Anyways I have dropped the idea of having a watermark .. just reset the property i.e. IsEditable=true served the purpose and then set the Text property ... Thanx all for ur comments