# Combo box default value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to use combo box and the following code is working but now I want to 
add to the combo box header default value ,i.e. there is value and like 
**Item** and when you open it you have the option to change it,how I can do that?

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem}"  
 Name="comboBox1" Text="Item" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
```

the code

```
private List<String> _items;
private String _selectedItem;
private String _selectedBusinessItem;
public List<String> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}

public String SelectedItem1
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}

private void InitCombo()
{
    Items = new List<string> { "item",  "Item2", "Item3" };
    SelectedItem1 = Items[0];
}
```

Comment: What is *the combo box header*?

Comment: @Sheridan- I.e. you dont need to open the combo box to see the first value,The first value is on the combo box and when you open it you see the others...

Comment: I don't see a OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem1");  And the binding is to SelectedItem (not SelectedItem1).

Comment: Try `SelectedIndex="0"` for `ComboBox` and in SelectedValue must `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem1}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're talking about the [`ComboBox.Text` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... from the linked page:

> Gets or sets the text of the currently selected item

This is *not* a free field that you can display a message in. It displays the value of the currently selected item from the `ComboBox.Items` collection. If the text is *not* in one of the items, then this `TextBox` 'should' *not* display that value.

However, there are always workarounds. The correct way to do it would be to define a new `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox` that contains a `TextBlock` that is overlayed on top of the selected item `TextBox` and hidden when required.

Some people think that that is too much work though and so you can find a number of alternative solutions in the [How to display default text “--Select Team --” in combo box on pageload in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf) post here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Beware because that *might* enable users to add your default message into the collection as an item... maybe by pressing Enter.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to understand you are asking, but I think you are just looking for the `ComboBox` to show the first value in the collection of `Items`.

I believe you can do this a few ways.

First you need to fix `SelectedValue` binding to match your property name, and drop the `Text="Item"`:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem1}"  
           Name="comboBox1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
```

From your code you can set the `SelectedValue1` property that you have to any of the `string` items. Examples of this:

```
SelectedValue1 = "item";
```

-or-

```
SelectedValue1 = Items.FirstOrDefault();
```

I used `FirstOrDefault` as a safety incase these items didn't exist.

-or-

```
SelectedValue1 = Items[0];
```

And there are several more options here. But I'm going to try and limit the scope of the answer.

Also, you should be able to set the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` to 0.

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem1}"  
           Name="comboBox1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"
           SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. List Items = new List { "item",  "Item 2", "Item 3" };
2. Set the Selected Index = 0, It will select the first element in the combo box Item-source

## XAML:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  
           Name="comboBox1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"
           SelectedIndex="0"/>
```