# Combo box with default value like --Select Gender --

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combo box which I want the default value to be `-- Select Gender --`

I have tried the following coding, and I got this error

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Please help

```
cboGender.ItemsSource = null;
cboGender.DisplayMemberPath = "Display";
cboGender.SelectedValuePath = "Value";
cboGender.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, oBinding);
cboGender.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Gender--");
cboGender.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: What if you set the property like this - `Text="--Select Gender--"` and remove this line `cboGender.Items.Insert(0, "--Select Gender--");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display default text "--Select Team --" in combo box on pageload in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf)

Comment: Why are you binding and inserting directly?

Answer (score 0):

Add `"--Select Gender--"` to your Collection **before** binding it to the `ItemsSource` (if you want it as first, remember to use Insert(0, ) and then after binding it, set the `SelectedIndex` to it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to call

```
cboGender.Items.Clear();
```

before the insertion of the default item.

OR

Just create your data source with the default value item before inserting any value in the combo box and write something like this:

```
cboGender.Items.Clear();
cboGender.ItemsSource = dataSource;
```

where dataSource would be the list with the all items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboGender"
 Text="--Select Gender--" />
```

if you don't need to choose this default value again after first selection