# How to set a prompt for combobox with mixed items?

Tags: wpf

There are nice solutions to the problem with combobox and prompt in WPF, but in my case I have mixed items -- image and text. So for example this solution (copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11671997/210342):

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox"
 IsEditable="True"
 IsReadOnly="True"
 Text="-- Select Team --" />
```

works fine as for prompt, but it has side effect, that when I select an item, the item in turn is not displayed correctly as selected -- it is presented in list OK, but after selection all combobox shows is `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem`.

So how to have a prompt (I don't insist of fixing this approach) and properly displayed mixed items?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in ugly way. I added a grid, put this combobox in the grid with `ZIndex=0`. I added extra button to the grid with `ZIndex=1`. This way I get an overlay. Any time users clicks on the button (combo is initially hidden) I open combobox programatically. When users selects anything from dropdown list of the combobox I hide the prompt button.