# How do I set the text a ComboBox displays when no item is selected (selected index is -1)?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that is data bound where I cannot insert sentinel items. I would like to show a default string if there is no selected value in the ComboBox.

I already tried using a style for this:

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="(unconstrained)" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```

but this completely broke data binding (no values were selectable).

Comment: use this code inside the combobox  `PlaceholderText="MyPlaceholder"`

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf
maybe it's what you need.

Comment: @soumyasambitKunda: `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox` has no `PlaceholderText` property. Perhaps that's WinForms?

Comment: @Andrey: Yep, that hack works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (not really fortunate) solution:
You could add another element to your list with value `"(unconstrained)"` at the first position and set `SelectedIndex` to 0 in your XAML. Then, when selection changes, you delete this element from the underlying list for `ComboBox` and move selected index one place up (since the head of the list has been deleted).

This is not elegant at all, but seems like the only solution since `ComboBox` does not have some kind of `Header` property and I am not sure what `Text` does on it (probably it is just inherited).

Comment: Unfortunately as I specified in the question I can't insert sentinel items to do this (the collection I'm binding to is already used in thousands of places and fixing them all to understand that the first item is a dummy value is infeasible)