# how to put text on combobox WPF (not tooltip)

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I  have this combobox on WPF:
http://i.snag.gy/UC7EN.jpg

I want  write text on the place that i marked on red
 text like: "choose from option" .
I tried to found the correct property to edit but i didn't succeeded to put a text there.

How can i do this?
i don't want tooltip or put text lable on the side of the combobox
, i want text where i marked please
thanks.

Comment: to search all the properties of combobox but not found it

Answer (score 2):

You can add events `DropDownOpened` and `DropDownClosed`. On `DropDownClosed` you can insert "Choose from option" using `comboBox.Items.Insert(0, "Choose from option")` and set `SelectedIndex = 0;`

On `DropDownOpened` you can delete this item.

Or try to put `TextBlock` inside `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be

```
<ComboBox Text="choose from option" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" ></ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the "Choose from option" string into your items:

```
cb.Items.Insert(0, "Choose from option");
```

Comment: but on this waht the user can choose on this
i want this will be only title

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a watermark combobox. A very simple method has been described here [How to display default text "--Select Team --" in combo box on pageload in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf).