# Merging text and XML data in combobox items in WPF

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, combobox, default

I have a ComboBox in WPF that gets data from XML as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <Book>
    <Name>Title1</Name>
    <Name>Title2</Name>
    <Name>Title3</Name>
  </Book>
</Root>

<ComboBox x:Name="cb_Book" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}, XPath=./Book/Name}"/>
```

I would like to merge a static default text along with items retrieved from XML. I had tried few approaches like CompositeCollection shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf) but was unsuccessful. Is there a best way to do this (preferably all in XAML)?

At the end ComboBoxItems should look like this:

```
Title1      #from XML
Title2      #from XML
Title3      #from XML
MoreTitle   #Static Default text
```

Comment: How about using [the 2nd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11671997/2998271) answer in the linked question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CompositeCollection** and **XMLDataProvider** is a way to go.

```
<StackPanel xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" XPath="./Root/Book/Name">
            <x:XData>
                <Root xmlns="">
                    <Book>
                        <Name>Title1</Name>
                        <Name>Title2</Name>
                        <Name>Title3</Name>
                    </Book>
                </Root>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
        <CompositeCollection x:Key="CompositeCollection">
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}}"/>
            <system:String>MoreTitle</system:String>
            <system:String>SomeMoreTitle</system:String>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CompositeCollection}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```