# C# Update Combobox text after SelectedItemChange

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox that i would like the physically displayed text to always remain the same.

I want the user to select an item which would then get passed in but then for the actual text on the combobox to remain the same.

on the

```
FileBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

event i find out which item has been selected with

```
 if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString() == "New File")
            {

            }
        }
```

(i will process this more later)

I then try and update the text back to being 'File'.

I have tried numerous approaches which dont seem to work.

I've tried simply doing

```
FileBox.text = "File";

this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            FileBox.Text = "File";
        });

FileBox.SelectedItem = "File";
```

When debugging it does actually seem like the .Text property gets updated, but it then seems to get overridden when the event finishes. For testing i have a button that does:

```
var text = FileBox.Text;
FileBox.Text = "File";
```

When i have selected "New File" the var text == New File

And the FileBox.Text code here works and updates it back to File

Do i need to set the text again outside of the SelectionChanged event, and if so how would i go about doing this?

Thanks

EDIT

I do not think this is a duplicate of the one posted as he wants his default to dissapear when something is selected, i want it to reappear

Comment: So basically, you want your combobox to have it's default selected item "Files" to be selected again once your code gets the item selected by the user?

Comment: Have you tried `FileBox.SelectedIndex = -1` ?

Comment: @Mac yes thats essentially what i need

Comment: @LennartStoop just tried this, this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watermark Behavior for ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211869/watermark-behavior-for-combobox)

Comment: Can you post your xaml for combobox? How do you populate the data?

Comment: @Mac my xaml is '<ComboBox Name="FileBox" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="0" Text="File" SelectionChanged="FileBox_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>' and then i simply do FileBox.Items.Add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is actually not ideal, you should use **MVVM** pattern, but this is my answer to your question, hope it helps.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FileBox"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  SelectionChanged="FileBox_OnSelectionChanged"
                  Width="180" Height="50" >
```

`Code-behind`

```
private void FileBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fileBox = sender as ComboBox;

            if (fileBox != null)
            {
                var selectedItem = fileBox.SelectedItem;

                // get the selected item.
                Debug.WriteLine(selectedItem);

                fileBox.SelectionChanged -= FileBox_OnSelectionChanged;
                fileBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                fileBox.SelectionChanged += FileBox_OnSelectionChanged;
            }
        }
```

Assuming that this is how you populate your control:

```
private void PopulateFileData()
        {
            FileDataList = new List<FileData>
            {
                new FileData{ FileName = "Files", Path = "" },
                new FileData{ FileName = "File 123", Path = @"c:\file1.txt" },
                new FileData{ FileName = "File 456", Path = @"c:\file2.txt" }
            };
        }

        private void FillComboBox()
        {
            foreach (FileData file in FileDataList)
            {
                FileBox.Items.Add(file.FileName);
            }
        }
```

Check your output window.