# wpf combobox with not focused empty text

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm using framework 4.0.

How to display grayed text in editable combobox when it is empty and not focused like in picture

[image: Example]

Comment: [How to display default text “--Select Team --” in combo box on pageload in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf)

Comment: no it's not same behavior

Comment: The [WatermarkComboBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WatermarkComboBox&referringTitle=Home) of the WPFToolkit (freely available) supports that .

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

There is no direct way to implement in WPF except using a TextBlock and ComboBox and laying them over each other.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21.545" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120.964" Margin="56.958,108.962,0,0">
        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Name="myComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <!--Items Here-->
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Text="Please Select" IsHitTestVisible="False" Foreground="Gray" x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="3.993,2.664,0,0">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Style.Setters>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=myComboBox, Mode=OneWay}" Value=""/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=myComboBox, Mode=OneWay}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

---

Sorry about this. I misunderstood the question previously. This answer is for UWP.

I think placeholder text is what you are looking for. Check this out [ComboBox.PlaceholderText property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.placeholdertext?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in MSDN Docs.

Comment: but it's work on universal platform , not framework 4.0

Comment: Hey @Json76, I am sorry. I misunderstood the question. I have updated the answer. Hope it helps you now.