# WPF ComboBox, Display SelectedValue Even If Not In ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF ComboBox I need to be able to display a **SelectedValue** that does not exist in the bound **ItemsSource** collection.

I've done a fair amount of searching and the only solution I've found so far is to instead bind to **Text** property and set **IsEditable**="True". I did use that in another part of my application but that won't work here because I can't risk the user providing invalid data.

In the XAML, the **ItemsSource** is bound to an ObservableCollection of available WorkEfforts. This list can change over time with items dropping out of the list. The **SelectedValue** is bound to the property of the  SelectedItem on a datagrid, Title.WorkEffort. A title is a seperate task, or change, that has a work effort assigned to it. Once assigned to a Title it shouldn't change, even if the work effort is no longer active.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkEfforts}"                       
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Title.WorkEffort}"                        
DisplayMemberPath="WorkEffortString"                        
SelectedValuePath="WorkEffortString"
IsEnabled="{Path=EditMode}"/>
```

**C# Code:**

```
ObservableCollection<WorkEffort> WorkEfforts = client.GetWorkEfforts();// Gets a list of all active work efforts from database

public class WorkEffort
{
public int WorkEffortID { get; set; }
public string WorkEffortString { get; set; }
public string ChargeNumber { get; set; }
}     

ChangeTitle Title { get; set;} //SelectedItem on a DataGrid whose ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection of ChangeTitles



public class ChangeTitle
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public int ChangeID { get; set; }

    public int TitleID { get; set; }

    public string WorkEffort { get; set; }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Text property with IsEditable="True" and IsReadOnly="True"

there also another methods here [How to display default text "--Select Team --" in combo box on pageload in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf)

Comment: please read suggestion provided by stackoverflow for writing question over stackoverflow. your question is not much clear for ur requirement

Comment: Adding IsReadOnly="True" coupled with IsEditable did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBox` in readonly mode does not support displaying items that does not exist in the `ItemSource`, but if you are ready for small trade of, you can achieve something similar.

If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `ChangeTitle` and add a `boolean` property similar to `IsAvailable`, and then instead of removing items from the collection `WorkEfforts`, you can set the `IsAvailable` to false.

Combine that with an `ItemContainerStyle` for your `ComboBox` similar to,

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=IsAvailable}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And you can show the unavailable items and at the same time prevent the users from selecting them. You'll be able to programatically select the unavailable items, but your users won't be able to select them by themselves.

Comment: `ComboBox` DOES supports displaying data out of the collection it's bound to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm aware of the `IsEditable` option, but what he wants is normal read only `ComboBox` which doesn't support the requested behaviour. I've made it clear for future readers, Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't end up using it for this but it gave me some ideas for where I can use it elsewhere. Thanks!