# How to bind selected Item from ListBox to ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, binding

I have a `ListBox` and items are generated dynamically. I also have a `ComboBox`.

Each item has a `string` property called 'Name'.

When I select this item on `ListBox`, I want to set default value or text of `ComboBox` with 'Name' of selected item from `ListBox`.

I could bind this with 'Text' property of 'TextBlock'. But I couldn't do it with `ComboBox`

Here's my code:

XAML

```xml
<ListBox Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Width="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <StackPanel>                   
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock {Binding Path=FileName}" />    
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </TextBlock> 
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I could bind this `TextBlock`:

```xml
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=MyList}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

But it doesn't work with `ComboBox`:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyList, Path=SelectedItem}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}" Text="{Binding Name}">                             
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is the enumerable used to populate the combobox'es item. SelectedItem is probably not an enumerable, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `ItemsSource` property on `ComboBox` to the `SelectedItem` in your `ListBox`. This does not work, as a bound items source must be a collection, in your case it is a single non-collection item.

Let us assume that you have bound the `ItemsSource` to a collection, e.g. `SourceList`. Then you can use the [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath?view=netcore-3.1) property to specify the property that should be used as label in the `ComboBox`, here `Name`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

If you want to set the default value, you can use the `Text` property, but you also have to set the `IsEditable` property to `true`, otherwise it will be ignored. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.text?view=netcore-3.1#remarks):

> When the IsEditable property is true, setting this property places initial text entered in the text box. When IsEditable is false, setting this value has no effect.

The downside to this is, that there will be a default text, but the `ComboBox` value can be edited.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SourceList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MyList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          IsEditable="True">
```

If editing is an issue with your requirements, you can have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426050/how-to-display-default-text-select-team-in-combo-box-on-pageload-in-wpf). There are workarounds, but they are quite complex and have some disadvantages, too.

Comment: So I just Created new List on my viewmodel and binded with Combobox Itemsource, and for the default value, I used Text property binding with SelectedItem.Name.