# How to hide stringformat if data is null

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, string-formatting, targetnullvalue

How to hide a stringformat when data is not present.Consider this sample

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount, StringFormat=Total: {0:C}}" />
```

in this case if Amount is null,Then it will show just Total:.How to hide this if Amount is null or empty

Comment: What are we considering?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"TargetNullValue" is what i was looking for.I ended up with this and it worked like a charm

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Text="{Binding Path=TotalMonths,
        TargetNullValue={x:Static System:String.Empty},
        StringFormat=Total: {0:C}}" />
```

Comment: Seems like you should give credit to rudigrobler and update your original post with these details.

Comment: Don't forget to add this namespace: xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Answer (score 35):

You either have to implement some sort of value converter ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356194/wpf-datatrigger-where-value-is-not-null)) or consider using the TargetNullValue property on the binding ([Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx))

Answer (score 22):

```
TargetNullValue=''
```

Will do also

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to work with here, but you can achieve something like this with:

- DataTrigger
- ValueConverter
- EventHandling in Code-Behind
- Binding on a (dependency-)property in a ViewModel encapsulating your business classes

Comment: I solved it using a value converter..but still helps to know any alternative approach...BTW cant handle in my business class since i am using datatables