# WPF binding replace zeros with blanks

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this WPF xaml binding element below:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value, StringFormat='0.00'}" />
```

If `Value` is `0`, I would like it to display an empty string.

I've tried:

```
DataMemberBinding="{Binding TotalStops, StringFormat='{}{0:#.#0}'}"
```

But when `Value` is `0`, it displays `.00` instead of an empty string.

Comment: There could be different ways to implement it, and WPF loves longcut ways (Converters, DataTriggers, etc.).. lol. But if I were you, I might have done something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387810/395500).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF, `StringFormat` support [the ";" section separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SectionSeparator).

Try this:

```
DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:#.#0;(0);''}}"
```

This example shows 3 value formats: positive, negative, and zero value formatting from left to right, separated by semi-colons.

[image]

The image reference from [article](http://www.shujaat.net/2014/03/wpf-conditional-formatting-with-section.html) by Muhammad Shujaat Siddiqi

---

This is just not limited to WPF, this can work with where ever a string format is used in general.

```
double x = 0.00;
x.ToString("#.#0;;A BIG ZERO");
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: That works, thanks! I am getting a dark green squiggly line under the ```''``` back to back quotes (expecting a close brace), any ideas? Prolly safe to ignore

Comment: @Rod: You might have to escape the single quotes for zero-value formatting. I don't have a WPF project up, but I might try that out in a little bit.

Comment: @Rod: Fixed it. Just remove the single quotes around the entire `StringFormat` expression. Please see the corrected answer abouve.

Comment: Thanks for the extra insight, I'd give you a double check if I could, lol.

Comment: What if I have a TimeSpan that is ```0:00:00```, is it possible to replace that with blanks? I've tried ``` DataMemberBinding="{Binding LunchBreak, StringFormat={}{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss;;''}}"```

Comment: @Rod: Unfortunately, the section formatter won't work on the TimeSpans (or may be DateTime too). One clean option is this case is a ValueConverter.