# Not logic in Binding conveter

Tags: xaml, data-binding

Is it possible to do something similar to this without introducing a new variable like

bool showsearch = !ShowUser;

Visibility="{Binding !ShowUser, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a style and a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx).  Apply the style to the element in question, and provide 2 datatrigger values- one to set visibility to true, one to false.  Similar to [DataTrigger where value is NOT null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356194/wpf-datatrigger-where-value-is-not-null)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, you have to create an inverted Visibility converter like this,

```
public class InvertedBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (value is bool)
        {
            flag = (bool) value;
        }
        else if (value is bool?)
        {
            bool? nullable = (bool?) value;
            flag = nullable.Value;
        }
        return flag ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility) value == Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Write a Converter BoolToCollapsed Converter ForExample

```
public class BoolToVisibleConverter : ConverterMarkupExtension<BoolToVisibleConverter>, 
              IValueConverter
{
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                CultureInfo culture)
            {
      bool obj=(bool) value;
      if(!obj)
      return Visibility.Collapsed;
      else
      return Visibility.Visible;

    }
     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
             CultureInfo culture)
             {
               Visibility obj=(Visibility) value;
               if(obj==Visibility.Visible)
               return true;
               else
               return false;
             }

}
```

Add a Static Resource to Window.Resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converter:BoolToVisibleConverter x:Key="BoolToCollapsed"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use it to a Grid,DockPanel Or anyother

```
 <DockPannel Visibility={Binding DockVisible, 
         Converter={StaticResource BoolToCollapsed}/>
```