# How to show a conditional checkbox in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to show a checkbox in the DataList **if** a 
 particular column in the binded Data Source is having a particular value.

Means look for a particular value. if exist then show checkbox else dont show.

Comment: You have to implement custom converter to check value for null or  to compare data in column. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356194/datatrigger-where-value-is-not-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the [DataList.ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx) event to get checkbox control and set `Visible` to `false` or hide with `display:none` style when it doesn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your aspx page:

```
<% if(valueToCheck == columnValue) {%>
<add checkbox here>
<% } %>
```

I haven't tried this, but it gives you the basic idea